# how to pass all open windows to command line in vim

Tags: command-line, vim-windows

I want to run clang-format on all open windows.

What I currently do, is:

- for each open window:

  - :!clang-format --style=file -i %

I have 2 issues:

1. the clang-format runs in shell, so it doesn't return to Vim until I press ENTER - how can I fix that? (tried fiddeling with `terminal` but couldn't make it work
2. How to run this on all open windows / all `git diff`-ed files? (I have a shell script I would very much like to bind to a Vim shortcut

clang-format shell script:

```
# unstaged
for FILE in $(git diff --name-only --relative)
do
    clang-format --style=file -i $FILE
done

# staged
for FILE in $(git diff --cached --name-only --relative)
do
    clang-format --style=file -i $FILE
done
```

Comment: Your two issues aren't really related to each other. It would be better to post them as separate questions.

Comment: The first question is answered in `:h :windo`. For the rest, as Rich suggested, post one question for one problem; don't make it a thread.